# Using Jquery to open a pop up on an href link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 loops within 1 form  where a link gets created within each loop. The first link on the first loop opens a pop up but all other links will open a new page. Not sure why all links don't open in a pop up

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#Popup').click(function() {
    var newwindow = window.open($(this).prop('href'), '', 
   'height=800,width=800');
    if (window.focus) {
        newwindow.focus();
    }
    return false;
});
});
</script>

<form method='post' target = '_blank'>

foreach(do something){ 
echo "<a href='newpage1.php?cmd=get stuff" id='Popup''>View</a>";
}

foreach(do something){ 
echo "<a href='newpage2.php?cmd=get stuff" id='Popup''>View</a>";
}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each link should have the same `class`, not have the same `id` (ids must be unique).

```
<a href="newpage1.php?cmd=get stuff" class="Popup">View</a>
```

Then, in your javascript, use the class selector.

```
$('.Popup').click(function() {
  // Will be applied to all in class
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That did it.